# Jquery mobile drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to make a mobile drop down menu for a project.

When I click the `#menu` the `#nav` goes down, but when I click
a second time, the `#nav` is not going back.

I've the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: it should be `.tap` instead of click : http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Answer (score 0):

Click should work, but you can add one more event for mobile, if click won't work tap will cover it :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').on('click tap', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```